# Two Texture Overlap in a Single Shape

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping

I've a rectangle with a texture. 
This shape is a play card.

Like a play card, i want to use a texture for the front face and
a different one for the back face.

I've tried with texture combiners (glTexEnvf) but this is not
what i need for my task. When rotate the shape, the two texture are mix each other,
ant not one over the other.

there is a way to overlap two distinct texture (front and back) in a single shape (square or rectangle)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just draw the quad twice with different textures? One with backface culling and one with frontface culling enabled.

Comment: Yes ok! is as solution... but for rotations and translations i must manage (repeat) two object! You know other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it nice and easy with shaders.
In the shader, use the normal transformed to camera coordinates and pick from one of the 2 textures based whether the notmal is pointing towards or away.